# Improvements of Dusart's lower bound for $ e^\gamma \log x \prod_{p\le x} \frac{p-1}{p}$.

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, products

Let $\gamma$ be the Euler-Mascheroni constant.
In [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.0442.pdf) paper (Theorem 6.12) it is proved that for $x\ge 2793$, $$ e^\gamma \log x \prod_{p\le x} \frac{p-1}{p}> 1-\frac{1}{5 \left(\log  x\right)^2+1}. $$

I've been wondering, is there a $C$ such that for $x>C$, $$ e^\gamma \log x \prod_{p\le x} \frac{p-1}{p}>1-\frac{1}{x^2} \space?$$

Comment: The remainder term encodes the Riemann hypothesis, you can't ask to improve it such drastically.

Comment: @reuns: Yeah I know, but back then I didn't really. I've just cleared the question and comments a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. [Diamond and Pintz proved](http://jtnb.cedram.org/item?id=JTNB_2009__21_3_523_0) that for some constant $c>0$, there are arbitrarily large values of $x$ for which
$$
e^\gamma \log x \prod_{p\le x} \frac{p-1}p < 1 - \frac{c\log\log\log x}{x^{1/2}\log x}.
$$
[Lamzouri conjectures](http://arxiv.org/abs/1410.3777v1) that the right-hand side can be improved to $$1 - \frac{(\log\log\log x)^2}{(2\pi+\varepsilon) x^{1/2}\log x}$$ but no further.

Comment: After a month I realised I might need that conjecture, so I must ask you: is the second displayed expression the RHS of an inequality with the same direction of your first one, or with that of mine?

Comment: At any rate, could I also ask if you happen to know the best known lower bound, for large enough $x$? I'd really appreciate it, apologies for getting back to this only now.

Comment: I think everything I know about this problem is contained in the papers I linked to. I believe the second displayed expression is intended to replace the RHS of my first display.

Comment: I see, thanks again.